# Certain steam games keep crashing my computer

Tags: steam

For some reason, that I can't find the answer to anywhere, some games that I bought through steam will allow me to play them for a few minutes and then crash my computer out of nowhere. I don't see a common thing about the games that do it and when it crashes a different colored screen comes up to look at until I turn my computer off. I have updated my drivers and deleted (but kept a copy just incase) my appcache, it also doesn't seem to be a graphics or ram problem from what I can tell at least as I can play games like dying light fine while games like dishonored crash. This has been a extremely annoying occurrence as it means I just wasted money on non-functioning games. If you have any idea of what I can do please tell me!
My computer specs are as follows:

RAM: 8 GB

CPU: Intel i5-4460 3.20 GHz

Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Same for me.
So far its Dishonoured and pcmark 8 that do it, possibly half life 2 as well. Thief, bioshock infinite and freespace 2 are fine. Dishonoured used to run fine.
I dusted my pc, reinstalled gpu drivers, updated chipset drivers, stress tested gpu (was fine), fault checked cpu and ram, used heaven bench mark (ran ok) and monitored temps n voltages using cupid hw monitor (again was ok) during the crash.

Os windows 10
cpu i7 2600k sandybridge
gpu evga super clocked gtx 570
Ram 8 gb corsair vengence